# Stop Device ringing through Alarm Ringtone

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am ringing my device in different activity and stopping it in different activity.
But the problem is device ringing is starting and stopping in same activity but not stopping in different activity..

The code is

```
     Ringtone ringtone;

     ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext.getApplicationContext(),
                RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE));

     AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
     int volume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, volume, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);

     ringtone.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

     ringtone.stop(); //ringing is not stoping
```

Is there any other way to stop forcefully all ringing in my device..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If ringing is same in all of the Activities I suggest you to use `Singleton` class to access your `RingtoneManager` and `AudioManager`

```
public class Utilities { 

   // static variable of Ringtone
   private static Ringtone mRingtone = null;

   // static variable of AudioManager
   private static AudioManager mAudioManager = null;

   // static method to get instance of Ringtone
   public static Rington getRingtone(Context mContext) { 

      if (mRingtone == null) {
           mRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext.getApplicationContext(),
            RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE)); 
       }

    return mRingtone; 

   } 

   // static method to get instance of AudioManager
   public static AudioManager getAudioManager(Context mContext) { 

      if (mAudioManager == null) {
           mAudioManager = mContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
       }

    return mAudioManager; 

   } 
}
```

Now in your Activity use something like this

```
Ringtone ringtone = Utilities.getRingtone(this)
AudioManager audioManager = Utilities.getAudioManager(this);

int volume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, volume, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);

ringtone.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

ringtone.stop(); //this will stop ringing
```

I also did something similar to create a `musicPlayer`, as music should stop even if the user stops it from notification or somewhere else, I created a `service` and used Singleton instances to `Play, Pause, Stop` etc,.

[Learn more about Singleton Classes here!](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-class-java/)

**Edit 1**

You code for removing Silent Mode looks fine to me, there must be something else wrong about Alarm not playing in Silent mode

This is an alternative solution for Sound in Silent Mode.

For removing silence/vibration mode I used the Alert Audio as `MediaPlayer` because music/media can be played even if the phone is on `DND` mode, I created an Emergency Alert App, which will make sound only when there is an emergency and some other `Certain Action` is performed.

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: hey can you tell me how to ring it, when device is in silent mode ...